# How can I force node.js to do a deeper recursion?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, node.js, recursion

I have a **memoized** recursive algorithm `f(n)`

When i run `f(1000)` everything works and it takes less than a minute to run.

When i run `f(10000)` i get a range error/ maximum call stack size exceeded.

I don't believe this error has anything to do with the efficiency of my algorithm (which is polynomial due to memoization) and seems to be more of a config thing.

I tried doing `node app.js --stack-size=32000` and that didn't make the error go away.  I'd have thought 10X the current stack size would suffice. Is that stack size potentially too small or is there a way to force/ set up a config in node to handle the `n = 10000` case?

Also the --stack-size option doesn't seem to do anything...i reduced it to "1" and my program ran just as fast.

Comment: Either don't use recursion, break it up into smaller asynchronous batches (if possible), or try a y-combinator.

Comment: ...also, I believe ES6 will allow proper tail calls, which means you shouldn't have call stack issues (assuming you're returning immediately). http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proper_tail_calls

Comment: @thefourtheye: In addition to the link above, the guy who built [continuum](http://benvie.github.io/continuum/)  has a [blog post](http://bbenvie.com/articles/2013-01-06/JavaScript-ES6-Has-Tail-Call-Optimization) about it.

Comment: you're saying it's impossible to use recursion in node..once the stack size is exceeded and that i can't somehow allocate more memory?

Comment: @algorithmicCoder may be memoization doesn't memoize enough?

Comment: Try putting the `stack-size`  before the file name. Just did a little testing, and that seems to make a difference. `node --stack-size=32000 app.js`

Comment: wow..someone told me to do the opposite this was what i was going to do at first! ha..thanks will try!

Comment: @cookie monster Please add your comment as an answer...it doesn't error out when i increase the stack size...

Comment: mmm... Interesting... Order also matters here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though Node requires its startup flags to be placed before the filename being executed.

```
node --stack-size=32000 app.js
```

Comment: Yes, because arguments after that are assumed to be arguments to the application and not to the node engine.

Comment: @Joe: That would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just a 2 penny tip here:

If your application throws you with stack overflow error, means you are doing something too large in one go, inheriting too many scopes.

Consider splitting login into async functions, so that way it can execute calls in separate contexts and that will prevent issue with stack overflow exception, as well as will allow application to share computation resources across whole logic, instead of selfishly use it in one function that actually is a bottleneck.